# PySpark: Select(col) or show() of a very large spark data frame

Tags: pandas, dataframe, select, pyspark

I have a large data frame (around 3000000 rows and 100 columns).
I want to convert it to Pandas dataframe. I have enough memory but it takes lots of time to do toPandas().

I try to split it to different columns to convert column by column. But still select(col) it takes lots of time.

Any idea:

- How to select(col) or show(10) of a very large data frame in pyspark?

or

- How to convert large spark dataframe to Pandas?

Comment: which version spark do you use ?

Comment: I used the Spark 2.3.0.

Comment: Then you can try using arrow,check this, https://arrow.apache.org/blog/2017/07/26/spark-arrow/